# Combine IdentityServer4 and MVC client

Tags: c#, identityserver4

I downloaded the sample IdentityServer and MVC client project from Github.
My goal is to create a portal environment, in which a user can authenticate and than proceed to request protected resources.

So what I did is move the Views from the MVC client to the IdentityServer project, changed the Client.cs to support a client on the same port and  added the following in the startup from the IdentityServer:

```
        var oidcOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "Cookies",

            Authority = "http://localhost:5000",
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "http://localhost:5000/",
            ClientId = "mvc",
            ClientSecret = "secret",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true,
            SaveTokens = true
        };
```

My question is are there any reasons, concerning security, I should not implement this and keep it seperated?

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this at all from a security perspective.

However I must warn you that you may run into a problem when dealing with cookies and tokens. Running them in separate projects implicitly separates the concerns of the MVC and IDS projects.

something that you might want to do is to fork your request pipeline by using `app.Map()`. (eg map IDS to "/identity" and the MVC project to "/ui")

Comment: Does this mean that the cookies and tokens are in separated in different authentication schemes? I'm not sure what you mean with mapping, what should be mapped?

Comment: Have you found out what app.Map() means?

Comment: Interesting, but not sure it would solve all the problems.  IdentityServer has certain built-in functionality for redirects, and for what triggers a sign-in action, and you still have to fight to get the right behavior.  For example, you typically trigger a sign-in when you hit a secure page, and after sign-in you are redirected to the secure page. But what if I just click sign-in from my main menu from an anonymous page? The expected behavior would be to return to the page last visited, which IdentityServer isn't set up to handle.